# How to check if the value is correct?

Tags: java, oop

In my setValue, I have incorrect error which I been testing in my testclass, in my testclass setValue is 0, therefore it expected to be 00 but it says in terminal 01
 What does my teacher mean by set the value on display to newValue, I tried this.value;. However it is still gives me error and additionally I tried to change to the symbols in it but the teacher stated it was incorrect I should just check if the value is right and then set it to newValue.
How do I solve this?
I appreciate the help.

```
    private int minLimit;
    private int maxLimit;
    private int value;
    private boolean wrapped;

    public NumberDisplay(int minLimit, int maxLimit) throws IllegalValueException {

        if (maxLimit > minLimit) {
            this.minLimit = minLimit;
            this.maxLimit = maxLimit - 1;
            this.value = minLimit;
            this.wrapped = true;
            // creates new number display with the value minimum limit
            // and the limits between maximum limit. if maximum limit is not greater than
            // minimum limit
            // it should throw exception

        } else {
            throw new IllegalValueException("felaktig");

        }

    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;

        // return the current value on display with integer number
    }

    public void setValue(int newValue) throws IllegalValueException {
        if (newValue < minLimit || newValue > maxLimit) {


            throw new IllegalValueException("Felaktig prova igen set time är felaktig");
            // set the value on display to newValue. if newValue is less greater than minimum
            // limit
            // or greater than value from display then throw exception
        } else {

            if (newValue == minLimit) {
                newValue = minLimit;
            }

        }

    }

    public String getDisplayValue() {

        if (this.value < 11) {
            return "0" + value;
        } else {
            return "" + value;
        }
        // return the current value with 0 infront of the value

    }

    public void increment() {

        if (this.value == maxLimit) {

            this.value = this.minLimit;
            this.wrapped = true;
        } else {

            this.value = +1;
        }

        // increases the display with one value and checks if maximum limit is reached
        // then
        // it should be converted to minimum limit

        // Consider to do the string delightful so all of values sets with as many as
        // numbers
        // the display should have. Values with low numbers should be zeros in front,
        // e.g. clock 9 09:00

    }

    public boolean diWrapAround() {
        if (this.value < maxLimit) {

            return this.wrapped = true;
        } else

            return false;

    }
    // it should return true if the display reached over maximum limit and started
    // from
    // minimum limit , otherwise it should return false,
    // use attribute wrapped to check boolean false or true.

}
```

Comment: In `setValue` you never assign `value`.

Comment: How do I check if it is correct value ?

Comment: @AdamLord But you already do that check in  `if (newValue < minLimit || newValue > maxLimit)`. Your problem is that in your else block when the value is correct you just don't do anything with it.

Comment: Yea but the teacher said, you should additionally check if the value is correct

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here public void setValue(int newValue) throws IllegalValueException {
    if (newValue < minLimit || newValue > maxLimit) {

        throw new IllegalValueException("Felaktig prova igen set time är felaktig");
        // set the current display value to newValue. if newValue is less greater than
        // minimum limit
        // or greater than value from display then throw exception
    } else {

        if (newValue == minLimit ) {

            this.value = newValue;
        }

    }

}
```

For somebody wondering about the answer, I changed this.value = newValue; to check if the value is right